# How to apply user defined formats to all the SAS data sets in library?

Tags: sas

For example, I have created a format NY as below:

```
Proc format;
value $NY
'Y'='Yes'
'N'='No'
;
run;
```

So I want to apply above format to decode the value as 'Yes' or 'No' to all the SAS data sets wherever Coded value Y or N is present.

Comment: Your format is correctly defined. You need to apply it now: `data foramtted;
 set begin;
 format var_in_question NY.;
 run;`

Comment: Hi, Many Thanks for reply.Above code will help me to decode/format the values of the variables which I am aware..means I have to explicitly mentioned the names of variables in the format statement the way you mentioned above..can you please tell me how to format or decode the values across data sets in a library without mentioning the name of the variable in format statement..I have defined so many formats to decode the variables so I need to decode them wherever the coded value has entered..your help is much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: In a solution where you have many variables of the same nominal type (Y or N) normalizing practice is to use a common suffix or prefix to represent the type.  So variable `diabetes` would be `diabetes_flag`, `diabetes_yn` or `has_diabetes`.  When all the same type variables follow the same naming convention it is easier to apply a formatting based on a rule versus scanning every value in all your tables.

Comment: Thanks  Richard for your help..

Comment: What is the question?  Note there is no way to tell whether a variable was designed to contain only Y/N values.  You could possible check your data to see if those are the only values that exist, but that doesn't mean that those are the only possible values.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the above, you need to process all the datasets in question, e.g.

```
* Assuming no variable names starting with underscore in data *;

data _NULL_;
  set ds end=_last;
  array _char [*] _character_;
  length _vars $4000;
  retain _vars;
  if _N_=1 then do _i=1 to dim(_char);
    * initialize a list of all character variables *;
    _vars=cats(_vars,"_",vname(_char[_i]));
  end;
  do _i=1 to dim(_char);
    * drop vars with values not in Y, N *;
    if _char[_i] not in ('Y', 'N') then _vars=tranwrd(_vars,cats("_",vname(_char[_i])),"");
  end;
  if _last then call symput("vars", translate(_vars," ","_"));
run;

proc datasets lib=work;
   modify ds;
     format &vars $ny.;
quit;
```

The above example works for one dataset, if at least one variable qualifies. This will apply your format to character variables with all blank values. You could automate this code over multiple datasets with a macro.